# Software to notify about interesting tags

Tags: discussion, tag-watching

Is there any software out there to notify about interesting questions based on my added tags as soon as they chip in?

Comment: Use the RSS feed for each tag (after possibly [enabling support for feeds in the browser](https://superuser.com/questions/261123) (and in some cases is only on the "[learn more](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/forth/info)" page for the tag))?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at http://stackapps.com on the **apps** tab?

Comment: Not really, going to check it out there now, thanks